# Обработчик изменения значения spinBox

Tags: c++, qt

Имеется главное окно на котором расположены LineEdit и кнопки: одна отправляет по uart  данные веденные в lineEdit,  другая отправляет команду на их применение, третья вызывает виджет на котором расположен spinBox,  который принимает значение установленное в lineEdit главного окна. Это уже реализовано.

Главное окно по своей сути принимает данные от пользователя и передает их в в девайс  собранный на stm32. Второе окно нужно для реализации непрерывной отправки данных (без кнопки "применить"). Пользователь изменил данные в spinBox, -  это привело к событию и обработчик  события определил в какую сторону произошло изменение, далее следует отправка: соответствующей команды и разницы значений spinBox до и после события. На этом этапе произошел затык. 
Очень рассчитываю на вашу помощь. B QT - новичек. Пишу свое первое приложение.

Вопрос:
Возможно ли в среде QT реализовать обработчик spinBox , в котором определялось изменение введеного значения, т. е. значение стало больше или меньше?

При этом нужно определить разницу между значением которое было до изменения и уже измененным.

Comment: В чем вопрос? Какой затык?

Comment: Возможно ли в среде QT реализовать обработчик spinBox ,  в котором определялось изменение введеного значения. Т. е. значение стало больше или меньше.

Comment: При этом нужно определить разницу между значением которое было до изменения и уже измененным.

Answer (score 1):

В классе окна заведите значение `предыдущее значение в QSpinBox (_prev)`:

```cpp
class Window :... {
    Window() {
        _prev = ui->spinBox->value();
        connect(ui->spinBox, &QSpinBox::valueChanged, 
                this, &Window::spinValueChanged);
    }

private slots:
    void spinValueChanged(int current) {
        // Вычисляем разницу
        int _d = _prev - current;
        // Проверяем - стало больше, меньше и так далее
    }

private:
    int _prev;
}
```